# Lost CoreData d/b after app crash; how to prevent loss from happening again

Tags: ios, core-data

I had a crash on my iPad app; the CoreData SQLite d/b went with it (no longer there).

Is this the way it's supposed to work, or is there something I can do to prevent it, other than fixing the cause of the crash, which had nothing to do with Core Data?  My guess is that during the crash, Core Data attempted to close the d/b, failed and deleted it instead.

How do I prevent the loss of the Core Data d/b at all costs?  (would take days to replace the data).

Comment: Just to be clear: are you using the SQLite or XML storage? Are you saving your changes to the persistent store? Can you show your setup code?

Comment: Using SQLite; changes are being saved to persistent store... I wasn't even near CoreData code when the crash occurred... (was moving between calendar squares... most had dates, but when I tapped on one without a date, the app crashed.)  Has been fixed!

Comment: That does not sound like something that should happen. Can you access the document folder and see if the sqlite file is missing?

Comment: This does not usually happen. Are you sure the database was actually being saved (i.e., are you checking for errors when you save?)? Are the sure the database is actually gone?

Comment: All I know is that the user that was doing Ad Hoc testing for me told me it was gone; when I tried to cause the crash, it too also disappeared using the Simulator.  I fixed the cause of the crash, but it can easily be removed.  I'll try that and get back to you both.

Comment: I just tested it and although the app crashed, the SQLite d/b is there.  Sorry for the panic; that's what I get for taking the user's word for it before checking myself.  (he's my son, so I just believed him!) If one of you would please form your comment into an answer, I would be happy to check it.  Thank you for your help; I appreciate it...